# Handling array and creating list of non required elements

Tags: perl

```
#array 

@myfiles = ("public", "A0", "B0", "KS");
```

Now, I just want A0, B0 and dont want any other elements like public and KS. So, for that I have below code:

```
my @MYFILES; 

foreach $names ( @myfiles )  {

  next if ( $names =~ m/public/);
  next if ( $names =~ m/KS/ ) ; 
  push (@MYFILES, "$names");

}
```

Now, next if statements helps to skip the elements that I dont want in my new array "@MYFILES"

But, instead of next if statements,  if I want to create a list of not required elements like public, KS and just call that in foreach loop which takes care and only gathers required elements like A0, B0 then how can it be done? I mean :

Something like creating hash %bad_dir = ( public = 1, KS = 1 ); and then calling that in foreach loop like below:

```
%bad_dir = ( public = 1, KS = 1 );

foreach $names ( @myfiles ) { 

 next if ( exists ( $bad_dirs{$names} )); 
 #but this code does not work ( Reason for creating hash is I will be having many such files that I don't need and I want to use next if statements. I want some shorter way. ) 

}
```

How can I do that.

thanks,

Comment: How to create a list of non-required items which "takes care" and only gathers required items? Perhaps you should try and explain that a bit better.

Comment: You better start using `use strict;`. You have `@MYFILES` and `@myfiles` which are two completely different arrays.

Answer (score 7):

[perldoc -f grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) is useful for filtering lists:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @myfiles = ("public", "A0", "B0", "KS");
my %bads    = map { $_ => 1 } qw(public KS);
my @MYFILES = grep { not exists $bads{$_} } @myfiles;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out grep: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html

If you have a short list, you can do this (using your own correct regex, of course):

```
my @myfiles = grep { !/public|KS/ } @myfiles;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're over thinking it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @files = qw(public A0 B0 KS);
my @not_required;
my @required;

for my $file ( @files )  {
    if ( $name =~ /public|KS/i ) {
        push @not_required, $name;
    }
    else {
        push @required, $name;
    }
}
```

This is **really** what you're saying: You want two arrays: One of required files and one of not required files. The `if/else` logic shows this quite plainly. You are either pushing a file into the `@required` or the `@not_required` array.

Also notice that the names should mean something. You're talking about *files*, so the array with the names should be called `@files` and not merely `@myname` which is singular even though you're talking about a collection of stuff.

And, `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. These will catch about 90% of all of your programming errors.